# JQuery Mobile, Keep new page in app on home screen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

Okay I am building a mobile application base off a web application with JQuery Mobile.

I have
`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

Set in the head tags of each page, in my navigation I am linking to a new page of /people.php for example and its busting out of the application that is on the homescreen that has no browser bars and opening up the browser to load that page. I want to load that page inside the application on the home screen. I am also going to have a few things like the login post to login_submit.php later and need them to stay in the application because the login_submit.php is going to bring them to the home.php page. I want everything to process in the application that is added to the home screen. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out. I built the code below. I just have to restructure all the links and it will work.

Here is the HTML

`<a href="javascript:navigator_Go('hello.php');">Go</a>`

Here is the javascript I run on the top of everypage. It gets all of the web pages and keeps them inside the full screen mode. If their is a lot of content on the new page it may take half a second longer to load but get the job done.

`function navigator_Go(url) {
    window.location.assign(url); // This allows links to stay in full screen mode
}`

Comment: One of the best things about this website is being able to come back 2 years later and find exactly what my work around was for this and put it to work again.